# Is it possible to run pl/sql anonymous block through OraOLEDB.Oracle provider?

Tags: oracle, ado.net, oledb

Is it possible to run pl/sql anonymous block through OraOLEDB.Oracle provider ?

This topic is not inculded into OraOLEDB.Oracle features list, but I still have a hope since execution of anonymous pl/sql is possible with ODP.NET (ADO provider).

P.S. If this feature was missed may be you could explain why? What makes it possible to realize execution of anonymous pl/sql block in ADO ?

Comment: OraOLEDB is a bit "old style", maybe that's the reason why it has not been developed for this provider.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to call  anonymous block through OraOLEDB.Oracle provider. Theoretically ODP.NET could be accessed through CLR methods, but I didn't succeed to do it quickly. May be anybody have allready prepared "assembly import scripts"?